# Como importar projetos​ e módulos do Android Studio via Git

Tags: android, android-studio, git

Olá! Boa tarde. Sou estudante de bacharel em sistemas de informação e estou praticando o desenvolvimento para Android. Meu professor disponibilizou um link do Git contendo um "pack" de cada assunto abordado em suas aulas, separados por modulos/pastas. Como se o projeto presente no Git, fosse na verdade vários sub projetos(chamamos isso de Módulos, certo?).
Ele desenvolveu na IDE do Android Studio e o meu problema está sendo em importar este projeto pois parece que, durante a importação, a IDE não entende esses módulos como sendo aplicações separadas e acaba gerando bugs seja pelos arquivos manifests ou relacionados ao grande build.

A primeira questão é que não sei se devo importar a partir de um modelo existente ou a partir de um novo pois tanto uma opção, quanto outra, geram situações diferentes com erros diferentes.  De qualquer forma, estou bem enrolado com isso e gostaria de saber qual seria o passo a passo ideal para realizar esta importação

link do git: https://github.com/raphaelframos/devmov1

link das Screenshots tiradas: https://postimg.org/gallery/upws86ty/

Problema com migração para Grandle: https://s26.postimg.org/lw9yvc2t5/Sem_t_tulo.jpg

Comment: Você consegue nos enviar imagens dos passos que você está executando pra importar estes arquivos no Android Studio?

Comment: 1) https://s26.postimg.org/yzx5p21bt/Sem_t_tulo.jpg
2) https://s26.postimg.org/g3rh57zg9/image.jpg
3) https://s26.postimg.org/vqiqild89/image.jpg
4) https://s26.postimg.org/tzzph3vp5/image.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Olá, primeiro você deve ter o GIT instalado em seu PC, você tem? 
Se o projeto estiver em um link você pode fazer um "git clone" pela IDE (Android Studio) que possui um plugin nativo para controle de Versão, no caso GIT.

Se o projeto está subdividido em links diferentes você deve fazer o import, pra cada link diferente.
Caso o projeto seja subdividido em branches, você só precisa fazer um fork e submeter cada alteração em uma branch, atraves do "git pull"

Tenta se basear nesse link, que ele mostra passo a passo como proceder.

Link: 
http://javapapers.com/android/android-studio-git-tutorial/

Comment: Opa! Eu tenho o Git instalado e já estou um pouco familiarizado com ele. Mas nesse caso específico, não estou sabendo importar pois está ocorrendo falhas. Temos diversos projetos ditos como módulos, dentro de um "todo". o link do meu git é esse: https://github.com/raphaelframos/devmov1 para você entender do que se trata.

Comment: Certo, você não consegue fazer "git clone https://github.com/raphaelframos/devmov1.git" ?

Comment: Depois de clonar o projeto TODO, você vai importar as partes (projetos) pela IDE

Comment: Consigo mas ele não gera o grandle build ou não sei explicar o que está acontecendo mas não está importando de maneira que a estrutura permaneça como deve ser no android studio. o link contendo as SS que tirei, pra entender melhor: https://postimg.org/gallery/upws86ty/

Comment: mas devo clona-lo a partir de um modelo existente ou um novo? e eu tentei ir adicionando modulo por modulo após a importação mas tive complicações de paths e tals. Realmente queria entender melhor para me expressar melhor aqui x.x

Comment: Ao clonar um projeto ele cria exatamente uma copia da estrutura definida no git. Recomendo você remover a existente e efetuar o clone novamente. Apos você clonar o projeto você deve abrir a IDE para importar dessa estrutura o projeto para você trabalhar. O Gradle é o gerenciador de dependências do Android, como o maven para projetos JAVA, então no Android Studio você deve ter uma opção para importar um Gradle Project. Apos importar a propria IDE vai organizar o projeto pra você.

Comment: Vou tentar aqui e te retorno

Comment: Não estou conseguindo resolver isso =\